# Gremlin query on Janusgraph through Spark. Error: Provider org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoShimService could not be instantiated

Tags: java, apache-spark, janusgraph, google-cloud-bigtable

**Current Architecture**
[image]

**Description**

1. I am using JanusGraph 0.6.2 for graph processing.
2. GCP BigTable as JanusGraph Backend/database.
3. Spark 3.0.0 with hadoop 2.7 for data processing, setup locally (planning to setup the env in GCP after the POC).
4. Gremlin Client and Java 11 as a client to run Spark Job, to do queries like traversal, find nodes and etc through *SparkGraphComputer*

**Problem**

I am able to trigger a query job, to do the node count on Spark using Gremlin Client, But I am facing issues triggering a query job using Java apis.

**Expectation**

Trigger a Query Job using Java APIs.

**Apache Spark Setup is done**
[image]
**Configuration working for Gremlin Client**

```
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# Hadoop Graph Configuration
#
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph
gremlin.hadoop.graphReader=org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.hbase.HBaseInputFormat
gremlin.hadoop.graphWriter=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat

gremlin.hadoop.jarsInDistributedCache=true
gremlin.hadoop.inputLocation=none
gremlin.hadoop.outputLocation=output
gremlin.spark.persistContext=true

#
# JanusGraph HBase InputFormat configuration
#
#janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend=hbase
#janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hostname=localhost
#janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.port=8586
#janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.table=janusgraph
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend=hbase
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.hbase.client.connection.impl=com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase2_x.BigtableConnection
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.google.bigtable.project.id= *****
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.google.bigtable.instance.id= *****
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.table= ******
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.hbase.regionsizecalculator.enable=false

# This defines the indexing backend configuration used while writing data to JanusGraph.
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.index.search.backend=elasticsearch
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.index.search.hostname=localhost

#
# SparkGraphComputer Configuration
#
spark.master=spark://RINMAC1714:7077
spark.executor.memory=1g
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/Users/rohit.pahan/portables/janusgraph-0.6.2/lib/*
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.kryo.registrator=org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoRegistrator
```

**Above config works and I get the result. Please follow the screenshot**
[image]
[image]

**Java API configuration which is not working for me**

GraphTraversalProvider.java

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.Constants;

public class GraphTraversalProvider {
    public static Configuration makeLocal() {
        return make(true);
    }
    public static Configuration makeRemote() {
        return make(false);
    }
    private static Configuration make(boolean local) {
        final Configuration hadoopConfig = new BaseConfiguration();
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("gremlin.graph", "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_GRAPH_READER, "org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.hbase.HBaseInputFormat");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_GRAPH_WRITER, "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_JARS_IN_DISTRIBUTED_CACHE, true);
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_INPUT_LOCATION, "none");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_HADOOP_OUTPUT_LOCATION, "output");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.GREMLIN_SPARK_PERSIST_CONTEXT, true);
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend", "hbase");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.hbase.client.connection.impl", "com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase2_x.BigtableConnectio");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.google.bigtable.project.id", "******");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.google.bigtable.instance.id", "*******");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.table", "******");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hbase.ext.hbase.regionsizecalculator.enable", false);
        
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.index.search.backend", "elasticsearch");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.index.search.hostname", "localhost");
        if (local) {
            hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.master", "local[*]"); // Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.
        } else {
            hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.master", "spark://MAC1714:7077");
        }
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.executor.memory", "1g");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty(Constants.SPARK_SERIALIZER, "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoRegistrator");
        hadoopConfig.setProperty("spark.kryo.registrationRequired","false");
        return hadoopConfig;
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        runSpark();
    }
    private static void runSpark() throws Exception {
        Configuration config = GraphTraversalProvider.makeRemote();
        Graph hadoopGraph = GraphFactory.open(config);
        Long totalVertices = hadoopGraph.traversal().withComputer(SparkGraphComputer.class).V().count().next();
        System.out.println("IT WORKED: " + totalVertices);
        hadoopGraph.close();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.janus</groupId>
    <artifactId>janus-spark</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>janus-spark</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <janus.version>0.6.2</janus.version>
        <spark.version>3.0.0</spark.version>
        <gremlin.version>3.4.6</gremlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-bigtable -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-bigtable</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-hadoop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-hbase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-hbase</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-solr</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware.kryo/kryo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
            <artifactId>chill_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- GREMLIN -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-gremlin</artifactId>
            <version>${gremlin.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-gremlin</artifactId>
            <version>${gremlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPARK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Error Logs**

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/rohit.pahan/portables/janusgraph-0.6.2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/rohit.pahan/portables/janusgraph-0.6.2/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/rohit.pahan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/rohit.pahan/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
0    [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkGraphComputer  - class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat does not implement PersistResultGraphAware and thus, persistence options are unknown -- assuming all options are possible
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.KryoShimService: Provider org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoShimService could not be instantiated
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.traversal.step.map.VertexProgramStep.processNextStart(VertexProgramStep.java:88)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:150)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:55)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.traversal.step.map.ComputerResultStep.processNextStart(ComputerResultStep.java:68)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:135)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:40)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:240)
    at com.janus.app.services.RunSparkJob.runSpark(RunSparkJob.java:20)
    at com.janus.app.services.RunSparkJob.main(RunSparkJob.java:14)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.KryoShimService: Provider org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoShimService could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.traversal.step.map.VertexProgramStep.processNextStart(VertexProgramStep.java:68)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.KryoShimService: Provider org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoShimService could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:804)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.KryoShimServiceLoader.load(KryoShimServiceLoader.java:97)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.kryoshim.KryoShimServiceLoader.applyConfiguration(KryoShimServiceLoader.java:58)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkGraphComputer.lambda$submitWithExecutor$1(SparkGraphComputer.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.newDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:380)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.getDefaultSerializer(Kryo.java:364)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoTypeReg.registerWith(GryoTypeReg.java:122)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoMapper.createMapper(GryoMapper.java:101)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoMapper.createMapper(GryoMapper.java:75)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoReader.<init>(GryoReader.java:71)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoReader.<init>(GryoReader.java:64)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoReader$Builder.create(GryoReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoPool.createPool(GryoPool.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoPool.access$100(GryoPool.java:40)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.gryo.GryoPool$Builder.create(GryoPool.java:227)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.HadoopPools.initialize(HadoopPools.java:51)
    at org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoShimService.<init>(JanusGraphKryoShimService.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor3.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.factories.ReflectionSerializerFactory.makeSerializer(ReflectionSerializerFactory.java:54)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private volatile long java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent.atomic" to unnamed module @1d9b7cce
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.buildValidFields(FieldSerializer.java:306)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:239)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.rebuildCachedFields(FieldSerializer.java:182)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.<init>(FieldSerializer.java:155)
    ... 34 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am still exploring Janusgraph and its processing capabilities with Spark. I have given all the details here, Let me know if any more details are required. It is a very new techstack for me. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<properties>
    <janus.version>0.6.2</janus.version>
    <spark.version>3.0.0</spark.version>
    <gremlin.version>3.4.6</gremlin.version>
</properties>
```

JanusGraph-0.6.2 depends on TinkerPop-3.5.3.
Mixing with other TinkerPop versions can easily lead to these kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks, @HadoopMarc I have tried with TinkerPop-3.5.3, Haven't worked for me. Do you have a code reference?

Comment: I believe this part of the docs is relevant: https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/serializer/ Beware that the java.util.atomic package may not be applicable to use in distributed computing. Apache Spark has its own data types for this purpose, see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators